# Preset amount of degree an image rotates per scroll

Tags: javascript

Is it possbile to set a preset amount an image rotates per scroll?

I created a rotate function with js, which rotates an image (gears in my case) by scrolling up and down the website. In my opinion it needs to rotate more degrees per scroll and Im trying to increase the degrees the image is rotating

**JS**

```
function rotate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  rot += e.deltaY * 0.5;
  leftGear.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;
  rightGear.style.transform = `rotate(${rot}deg)`;
}


let rot = 0;
const leftGear = document.querySelector(".leftGear");
document.body.onwheel = leftGear.onwheel = rotate;
const rightGear = document.querySelector(".rightGear");
document.body.onwheel = rightGear.onwheel = rotate;
```

**html**

```
<div class="gearBox">
  <!--<img src="img/proxcopAIO.png" height="60">-->
  <img src="img/gearProxBlue.png" id="gearText" height="100">
  <div class="rightGear" id="rightgear">
    <img src="img/gear.png" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="leftGear" id="leftgear">
    <img src="img/gear.png" height="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing '0.5' as factor but somehow it doesnt change anything, or maybe its a false thought of mine

Answer (score 0):

it's because your rotate the whole div which width is 100% of your browser.
Add a width to your div, it will solve your problem

```
.rightGear{
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Doent seem to work. The rotation of the image is already working and also as intended its just the degree I want to increase

Comment: ok, i misunderstood the problem.
deltaY is a difference between 2 point in the Y direction. in a case of a scroll, this difference is always the same that's why the rotation doesn't increase.
Try to replace `deltaY` with `clientY`, it should be what you expect.